# CKEditor editor.resize() not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using multiple Ck Editor in a page and I want to give fixed height and width in the editing area for one of them.I tried with editor.resize('150','250',true) .But its not working.Can anyone help me in this topic?Here is my code:

```
$('textarea#Users_about_me').ckeditor({
    toolbar: [{
        name: 'basicstyles',
        items: ['Bold', 'Italic']
    }, {
        name: 'paragraph',
        items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList']
    }],
    height: '300px',
    width: '100%'
});
```

Thanks,
Biplab

Comment: did you tried giving pixels?

Comment: try my another answer

Answer (score 2):

```
    <textarea id="myfield" ></textarea>
     CKEDITOR.replace('#myfield',{customConfig :'',width:'700px',height:'700px'});
```

Comment: width or height is used for whole editor.I just want to give in the editing area.

Answer (score -1):

you have to apply resize to editordialog not to the editor.

try like this

```
editor.dialog.resize(150,250);
```

Following link will help to give more info about properties of ckeditor.

[CKEDITOR](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog)

Comment: "the editing area" is explicitly mentioned in the question. What does it have to do with dialogs then?

Comment: @oleq-there is no resize property for editor.you have follow above syntax to resize.check the link once

Comment: @MaheshMajeti here is the link http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_howtos_interface-section-2